# Can't get Ubuntu 18.04 installed as dual boot on Dell Precision 7540

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, dell

I have brand new Dell Precision 7540 with Windows 10 Pro pre-installed and like to install an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as dual-boot.

I downloaded the current Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.3 LTS as an iso-file and created a bootable usb-key with it (rufus).

When I run the Ubuntu-Boot-Manager (selecting the usb-key in the boot-menu) every option gets the following errors:

```
[...] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[...] nouveau 0000:01:00:0: unkown chipset (1670000a1)
[...] [drm:lspcon_init [i915]] *ERROR* Failed to probe lspcon
[...] [drm:intel_ddi_init [i915]] *ERROR* LSPCON init failed on port D
...
(initramfs) mount: mounting /cow on /root failed: invalid argument
overlay mount failed
```

According to the canonical certification website the current 18.04 should be compatible with this dell-device:
https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201904-26941

What I did already:

- shrinked the windows-partition to get space for the ubuntu-partition
- changed the SATA-Setting from RAID On to AHCI
- disabled and enabled the Secure-Boot-Option

Where should I look for a solution?
Is it a compatibility issue between Ubuntu and the Dell-Components (drivers)?
Or did I something wrong?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think you need the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset` to make it work with the nvidia graphics chip. Later on after installation, you may also need `nomodeset` and later on you might install a proprietary nvidia driver for the graphics chip to perform well.

Comment: Another problem could be that Rufus cannot make a persistent live drive with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. So if you tried that, please try again and make a live-only USB drive (or use another tool to make it persistent live: [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/)

Comment: @sudodus: yes, Rufus were the problem. With mkusb and the live-only option everything was working well. Ubuntu is installed (but without WiFi-drivers, will check that as next)

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you with this step :-) *If you need help with the wifi driver, please ask a new question.* (There are other people who know how to solve such problems, and they would not find your question about wifi here.)